# How to use OneToOneField in the Model and save both table with class-based-views?

Tags: python, django, forms, one-to-one, django-class-based-views

I need to register a modelform in the database, but as I have a OneToOneFiel in the model, I don't know what is the best way to register the information in the two tables in the database with a class-based-views. The following code worked for me, but it doesn't seem like the right solution, or pythonic solution.

**models.py**

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail', max_length=30, unique=True)
    logradouro = models.CharField('Logradouro', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Assinante(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.OneToOneField(Pessoa, models.DO_NOTHING)
    qualquer = models.CharField('Qualquer', max_length=20)
    aceito = models.BooleanField('Aceito', default=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pago
```

**forms.py**

```
class AssinanteModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nome = forms.CharField(label='Nome', min_length=8, max_length=100)
    email = forms.CharField(label='E-mail', max_length=30)
    logradouro = forms.CharField(label='Logradouro', max_length=50)
    qualquer = forms.CharField(label='Qualquer', max_length=20)
    aceito = forms.CheckboxInput()

    def send_mail(self):
        # Anything
    
    class Meta:
        model = Assinante
        fields = ['nome', 'email', 'logradouro', 'aceito']
```

**views.py** (not pythonic, I believe)

```
class AssinanteView(FormView):
    template_name = 'club.html'
    form_class = AssinanteModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        pessoa = Pessoa(
            nome=form.cleaned_data['nome'],
            email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
            logradouro=form.cleaned_data['logradouro'],
        )
        assinante = Assinante(
            qualquer=form.cleaned_data['qualquer'],
            aceito=form.cleaned_data['aceito'],
        )
        pessoa.save()
        assinante.pessoa = pessoa
        assinante.save()
        # form.send_mail()
        messages.success(self.request, "Cadastro realizado com sucesso.")
        return super(AssinanteView, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('club', AssinanteView.as_view(), name='club'),
]
```

**template html (cleaned)**

```
<form action="{% url 'club' %}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="logradouro">
    <input type="text" name="qualquer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="aceito">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Continuar</button>
</form>
```

I believe that the correct thing would be to use self.form_class.save (form) according to the code below but it did not work, as it seems that it only registers in one of the tables in the database.

> Exception Type: IntegrityError
> Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'pessoa_id' cannot be null")

**views.py**

```
class AssinanteView(FormView):
    template_name = 'club.html'
    form_class = AssinanteModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form_class.save(form)
        form.send_mail()
        messages.success(self.request, "Cadastro realizado com sucesso.")
        return super(AssinanteView, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a more correct way to do this, using `self.form_class.save(form)`?

Comment: Can someone help?